# Pascal duplicate identifier

Tags: pascal

```
program Noname4;

  function minutes (Amin, Bmin :integer) : integer;

  function time (Aval, Bval :integer) : integer;
  begin
    if (0 <= Aval) and (Bval < 24) then
      time :=Bval - Aval;
    if (0 <= Amin) and (Bmin < 60) then
      minutes :=Bmin - Amin;
  end;

 var Aval, Amin, Bval, Bmin, n , x , i , y :integer;
   duom, rez : text; 
 begin
   readln(Aval, Amin, Bval, Bmin );
   writeln(time(Aval, Bval));
   writeln(minutes(Amin, Bmin));
   readln;
   assign(duom, 'Duomenys2.txt');
   Reset(duom);
   Readln(duom, n );
   assign(rez, 'rezultatai2.txt');
   rewrite(rez);

   for i := 1 to n do
   begin
     Readln(duom, Aval, Amin, Bval, Bmin);
     x := time(Aval, Bval);
     y := minutes (Amin, Bmin);
     writeln(rez, x);
     writeln(rez, y);
   end;
   close(duom);
   close(rez);
 end.
```

Hello, I am getting a error (duplicate identifier, identifier already defined in line 2). It shows red in the ( duom, rez : text; ) line. Can't find out why

---

```
program Noname4;

function minutes (Amin, Bmin :integer) : integer;
function time (Aval, Bval :integer) : integer;
begin
  if (0 <= Aval) and (Bval < 24) then
    time :=Bval - Aval;
  if (0 <= Amin) and (Bmin < 60) then
    minutes :=Bmin - Amin;
end;
var Aval, Bval, n , x , i , y :integer;
  duom, rez : text;
begin
  assign(duom, 'Duomenys2.txt');
  Reset(duom);
  Readln(duom, n );
  assign(rez, 'Rezultatai2.txt');
  rewrite(rez);
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    Readln(duom, Aval, Bval, Amin, Bmin);
    x := time(Aval, Bval);
    y := minutes(Amin, Bmin);
    writeln(rez, x);
    writeln(rez, y);
  end;
  close(duom);
  close(rez);
end;

begin
end.
```

I did what you said, the program now works fine except it doesn't write the the answer in 'Rezultatai2.txt' file.

Comment: Your `Amin` and `Bmin` variables are already parameters of your `minutes` function.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
var Aval, Amin, Bval, Bmin, n , x , i , y :integer;
duom, rez : text;
```

to:

```
var Aval, Bval, n , x , i , y :integer;
duom, rez : text;
```

they are already defined as variables passed into your minute function